# scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs single function computes both f and fprime

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, gradient

I'm using `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(f, init_theta, fprime)` to minimize `f`, which has gradient `fprime`. I compute `f` and `fprime` in a single function because most of the computation is the same so there's no need to do it twice.

Is there any way to call `fmin_bfgs()` specifying a single function that returns both `f` and `fprime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to save on computation time rather than just combine the calculation of `f` and `f'` for code convenience, it seems like you need an extra wrapper around your function to cache values, since `fmin_bfgs` doesn't seem to allow you to pass such a function (unlike some other optimization functions).

Here's one way to do that, maintaining the 10 most recently evaluated points in a little cache. (I'm not sure whether calls to this function need to be thread-safe: probably not, but if so, you'll probably need to add some locking in here, I guess.)

```
def func_wrapper(f, cache_size=10):
    evals = {}
    last_points = collections.deque()

    def get(pt, which):
        s = pt.tostring() # get binary string of numpy array, to make it hashable
        if s not in evals:
            evals[s] = f(pt)
            last_points.append(s)
            if len(last_points) >= cache_size:
                del evals[last_points.popleft()]
        return evals[s][which]

    return functools.partial(get, which=0), functools.partial(get, which=1)
```

If we then do

```
>>> def f(x):
...    print "evaluating", x
...    return (x-3)**2, 2*(x-3)

>>> f_, fprime = func_wrapper(f)

>>> optimize.fmin_bfgs(f_, 1000, fprime)
evaluating [ 994.93480441]
evaluating [ 974.67402207]
evaluating [ 893.63089268]
evaluating [ 665.93446894]
evaluating [ 126.99931561]
evaluating [ 3.]
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 4
         Function evaluations: 7
         Gradient evaluations: 7
array([ 3.])
```

we can see that we don't repeat any evaluations.

Comment: Nice implementation! I thought of trying to use this strategy, but I was not sure how to make an array hashable. Also, I was hoping that there was a feature already built into scipy.optimize to handle this. Apparently, others have requested the feature because it's supposed to be part of scipy 0.11, which is not yet released. Thank you for providing this design pattern!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Python function `f(x)` that returns both the function value and the gradient:

```
In [20]: def f(x):
   ....:     return (x-3)**2, 2*(x-3)
```

Then just pass the outputs separately like so:

```
In [21]: optimize.fmin_bfgs(lambda x: f(x)[0], 1000, lambda x: f(x)[1])
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 4
         Function evaluations: 7
         Gradient evaluations: 7
Out[21]: array([ 3.])
```

Comment: This doesn't actually save any computation though, it just throws out the result of one or the other. Which I guess only matters if BFGS frequently asks for the function value and the gradient at the same point: I'm not familiar with the algorithm, but it seems like it might.

Comment: That's fine. `lambda x: f(x)[0]` is a `callable`. That's all that `fmin_bfgs` needs. It doesn't care about the internals of that callable.

Comment: Yes: obviously your approach will work. But it'll repeat unnecessary computation, which seems like what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh I see. I interpreted that point as `f` contains computation common to both the function and the gradient, not that `fmin_bfgs` repeats computation.

Comment: This is how I'm handling it now. I would like to save on computation. I notice that the feature I'm looking for is supported in scipy 0.11, which is yet to be released.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly. But `scipy.optimize.minimize` does let you do this. You can pass a the value True for fprime instead of a function. This signals that f returns a tuple of the function value and the gradient. You can invoke `minimize` with method='BFGS' to get the effect you want.

It's enlightening to look at [the source code for `minimize`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L411). Both it and fmin_bfgs eventually call _minimize_bfgs, which takes f and fprime as separate function arguments. When fprime is a boolean,`minimize` cleverly constructs fprime as an object that remembers the last value returned by f, and caches the gradient information.